# replacing one word by another in an entire directory - unix

Tags: regex, unix

I'm refactoring some code, and I decided to replace one name by another, let's say `foo` by `bar`. They appear in multiple `.cc` and `.h` files, so I would like to change from:

```
Foo key();
```

to

```
Bar key();
```

that's it, replace all the occurrences of `Foo` by `Bar` in Unix. And the files are in the same directory. I thought about

```
sed -e {'s/Foo/Bar/g'}
```

but I'm unsure if that's going to work.

Comment: Use an IDE with a refactoring feature.

Comment: @Kevin I can't, I'm using `VIM` and I'm logged remotely to the server

Comment: As much as I love vim, it's quite risky to do refactoring with `s///`.  At least open them in vim and do `:s/\<Foo\>/Bar/gc`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
sed -i'.bak' 's/\bFoo\b/Bar/g' *.files
```

Comment: @philippe `-i` option does in-file substitution. If something goes wrong, you will have a backup of your original files which would be renamed to have `.bak` extension.

Answer (score 1):

I would use sed:

```
sed -i.bak -e '/Foo/ s//Bar/g' /path/to/dir/*.cc
```

Repeat for the *.h files

Answer (score 1):

I don't use sed alot, but iF you have access to Perl on the command line (which many unix's do) you can do:

```
perl -pi -e 's/Foo key/Bar key/g' `find ./ -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cc'`
```

This will find (recursively) all files in the current directory ending with .h or .cc and then use Perl to replace 'Foo key' with 'Bar key' in each file.

Answer (score 1):

I like Jaypal's sed command.  It useds `\b` to ensure that you only replace full words (`Foo` not `Foobar`) and it makes backup files in case something went wrong.

However, if all of your files are not in one directory, then you will need to use a more sophisticated method to list them all.   Use the find command to send them all to sed:

```
 find . -print0 -regex '.*\.\(cc\|h\)' | xargs -0 sed -i'.bak' 's/\bFoo\b/Bar/g'
```

Comment: At least use `find -print0 / xargs -0`, `-exec` would be better

Answer (score 0):

You probably have perl installed (if its UNIX), so here's something that should work for you:

```
perl -e "s/Foo/Bar/g;" -pi.save $(find path/to/DIRECTORY -type f)
```

Note, this provides a backup of the original file, if you need that as a bit of insurance.

Otherwise, you can do what @Kevin mentioned and just use an IDE refactoring feature.

Note: I just saw you're using **Vim**, here's a quick **[tutorial on how to do it](http://www.usevim.com/2012/04/06/search-and-replace-files/)**